# Test reusable bundle for symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I try to create a reusable bundle with one service who implement an interface and one annotation.
In DependencyInjection I create Configuration class with the method getConfigTreeBuilder

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $treeBuilder->root('sow_binding', 'array');
    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

and Extension class who load services.yaml in config directory.

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
        $container,
        new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
    );
    $loader->load('services.yaml');
}
```

I created one test who create a fake class who use my annotation and my service but I get this message when I execute it :

```
Error : Class 'SOW\BindingBundle\Service\BindingService' not found
```

In my test I instantiated my service like this (with right import) :

```
$bindingService = new BindingService($reader, 'SOW\Annotation\Binding');
```

Here my services.yaml file :

```
parameters:
    binding.annotation.class: SOW\Annotation\Binding

services:
    SOW\BindingBundle\Service\BindingService:
        alias: sow_binding.binder
        public: true
        arguments:
            - "@annotations.reader"
            - "%app.binding.annotation.class%"
```

Why my test can't find my service ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the app from binding. annotation. class as its not a valid reference.